# Is it common for parameters to be passed between routes in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

We don't use state management in this project
In the header, there are buttons,
I want to listen to button clicks inside  the body (route)
As a result, I passed the parameters as follows:

```
export default function Body({ version }) {
   const [selectedHeaderButton, setSelectedHeaderButton] = useState({
        index: undefined,
        label: "Select Vehicle Plan",
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <HeaderBar open={open} drawerWidth={drawerWidth} handleDrawerOpen={handleDrawerOpen}>
                <Header
                    selectedHeaderButton={selectedHeaderButton}
                    setSelectedHeaderButton={setSelectedHeaderButton}
                    version={version}
                />
            </HeaderBar>
            <MainRoutes
                selectedHeaderButton={selectedHeaderButton}
                setSelectedHeaderButton={setSelectedHeaderButton}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

And MainRoutes component :

```
export default function MainRoutes({ selectedHeaderButton, setSelectedHeaderButton }) {

    return (
        <main>
            <div>
                <Routes>
                    <Route
                        exact
                        element={
                            <Rpo
                                selectedHeaderButton={selectedHeaderButton}
                                setSelectedHeaderButton={setSelectedHeaderButton}
                            ></Rpo>
                        }
                        path="/"
                    />

             
                    {/* <Route component={Page404} /> */}
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}
```

It works fine for me, but I heard from my friend to work that it is not common / best practice to transfer parameters this way.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use state management tool or context, a few months later the project will become unmanageable mess. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context

Comment: Thank you for your response. I totally agree with you. However, my manager does not want to implement state management at this time. I have the following options:
 1. Move parameters within routes.
2. move all the logic to the header and use singleton files for she data between header and body

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you're using React without _any_ state management. Does your manager understand how React works?

Comment: That's what I ask myself! We use props drilling

Comment: So you don't have any interactive parts of your app/interface that require state management? I'd question the use of React at all in this case.

Comment: It may have been clearer than I thought, but we use useState for state management, but not on a global level like redux or mobx does

Comment: @LiorYitzhak, don't pass the data through parameters, that's not how you should work with react and don't store all the data in single component (header in your case) for the same reason, please just use context that would be enough as a solution for the moment and the transition to context should be quick